# Ampersand vs plus for concatenating strings in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, string-concatenation

In VB.NET, is there any advantage to using `&` to concatenate strings instead of `+`?

For example

```
Dim x as String = "hello" + " there"
```

vs.

```
Dim x as String = "hello" & " there"
```

Yes, I know for a lot of string concatenations I'd want to use `StringBuilder`, but this is more of a general question.

Comment: @Tim - Thanks, I searched but somehow didn't find that, thank you for posting it.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I've heard good, strong arguments in favor of both operators.  Which argument wins the day depends largely on your situation.  The one thing I can say is that you should standardize on one or the other.  Code that mixes the two is asking for confusion later.

The two arguments I remember right now for favoring `&`:

- If you're not using `Option Strict` and have two numeric strings, it's easy for the compiler to confuse your meaning of of the `+` operator with, you know, arithmetic addition
- If you're updating a lot of older vb6-era code it helps not to have to convert the concatenation operators ( and remember: we want consistency).

And for `+`:

- If you have a mixed vb/C# shop, it's nice to only have one concatenation operator.  It makes it easier to move code between languages and means just that much less of a context switch for programmers when moving back and forth between languages
- `&` is almost unique to VB, while `+` between strings is understood in many languages to mean concatenation, so you gain a little something in readability.

Comment: There is a problem with `&` for string concatenation. From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te2585xw.aspx) "The & operator always widens its operands to String, regardless of the setting of Option Strict". So for example `"Hello " & 2.5` will silently convert the 2.5 to a string using the regional settings (you might get `"2.5"` or `"2,5"`). Fine if that was what you wanted. I would much, much rather be forced to specify it explicitly.

Comment: @MarkJ Actually VB.NET is on a better footing here than C#, even, because at least you have the choice of using `&`. In C#, string concatenation can *always* perform an implicit `ToString`, and there's no way to turn this off. I can't tell you how much I hate this. Glad to see VB.NET got this one right (shocking!)

Answer (score 50):

Microsoft's [preference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9c5t70w2.aspx) is for VB programmers to use `&` for strings and not `+`.

> You can also use the + operator to concatenate strings. However, to eliminate ambiguity, you should use the & operator instead.

Comment: +1 for using the MSDN docs rather than personal opinion! Both are valid, but only one is offical. :) You may also want to link to the docs on & - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wfx50zyk.aspx

Answer (score 16):

I prefer using `&` for string concatenations in VB.NET

One reason for this is to avoid any confusion e.g

```
MessageBox.Show(1 & 2) ' "12"
MessageBox.Show(1 + 2) ' 3
```

Comment: This is only a problem with `Option Strict` off.

Comment: Good point - although I think the default is off?

Comment: Hi Barry, it might be good to also put down the outcome of each example. E.g. as comment `// "12"` vs `//"3"`. This would help illustrate your point for those, that don't know the difference yet.

Answer (score 10):

It's safer to use & since you're making your intention clear to the compiler (I want to concatenate these two values and they should both be converted to strings).

Using + can lead to hard to find bugs if the strings are numerical values, at least if the option strict is off.

For example:

```
1 + "1" = 2 ' this fails if option strict is on
1 & "1" = 11
```

Edit: though if you're concatenating a non-string you should probably use some better method anyway.

Answer (score 5):

I suppose it is historical (non .NET Visual Basic uses &, not sure why they introduced the +) and a matter of taste (I prefer & because we concatenate strings, we don't add them...).

Comment: Good point about the meaning of + being overloaded with arithmetic operators, whereas & usually just means "and".

Comment: We concatenate strings, we don't bitwise-and them.  Sadly, neither of these operator choices is free from overloaded meaning.

Comment: @ESV I don't think Visual Basic (before .NET) had bitwise operators, so there was no overloaded meaning there. But indeed, the argument is void for languages using & for other usages.