# VB.NET assigning string value ---- String1 = String1+String2

Tags: vb.net, string, vb6

Back in VB6, you were able to re-assign a string's value to itself plus other string values, such as:

```
str_Duplications_Line = str_Duplications_Line & pRow_Prime.Value(i_FieldNum)
```

Now, intellisense is not picking it up as an error, nor is the compiler complaining, but when it is ran, it bombs out on that line, and other multiple line such as these:

```
str_Duplications_Line = str_Duplications_Line & ","

str_Duplications_AllFields = str_Duplications_AllFields + str_Duplications_Line + vbCrLf
```

Any idea why this is happening, and how I can fix this? Or at least, simulate the same thing in VB.NET?

Comment: "Bombs out"?  Is there an error?  Errors usually contain useful information about what went wrong.  Both the `+` and `&` operators can be used to concatenate strings.  Somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006153/vb-net-ampersand-vs-plus-for-concatenating-string

Comment: What do you mean by `bombs out` ? What error are you getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the diference between `&` and `+`

```
"abc" + "def" = "abcdef"
"abc" & "def" = "abcdef"
"111" + "222" = "111222"
"111" & "222" = "111222"
"111" & 222 = "111222"
"111" + 222 = 333
"abc" + 222 = conversion error
```

If any one operand is null, you may get an error.

Comment: Of course if you have Option Strict On `"111" + 222` and `"abc" + 222` will not compile

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're not trying to concatenate a null to your string

Comment: I will do an if-then statement to make sure it does not assign nulls thank you!

Comment: But isn't it legal to concatenate null to a string in VB? AFAICR null is treated as empty string ""