# String not getting concatenated in VB

Tags: vb.net

I declared a string s like this

```
Dim s As String=""
```

And I am trying to build a keylogger that e-mails String "s" by concatenating keystrokes. A sample code snippet is as follows

```
Dim hotkey5 As Boolean
        hotkey5 = GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.E)
        If hotkey5 = True Then
            String.Concat(s, "E")
        End If
```

But nothing is getting concatenated to String s. Why is that so?

Answer (score 2):

In .net Strings are immutable. So you need a new string to hold the results of the the concatenation - which is the concatenated string.

```
    Dim hotkey5 As Boolean
    hotkey5 = GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.E)
    If hotkey5 = True Then
        s= String.Concat(s, "E")
    End If
```

Comment: Just to say, GetAsyncKeyState will return a short, not a boolean ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
Dim hotkey5 As Boolean
hotkey5 = GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.E)
If hotkey5 = True Then
    s+="E"
End If
```

### Synopsis

VB.Net provides an ability to add or concatenate two strings using `+` operator. It also can be used many way.
VB.Net provides an ability to add or concatenate two strings using `+` operator. It also can be used many way. 
Let `Dim Valu1 as String=”1”` and `Dim Valu2 as String=”2”`. Then `Dim concatenate = Valu1+Valu2`. So the value will be `”12”`. Or we  can, `Dim concatenate = Valu2+Valu1`. Then the value will be `”21”`. So it is pretty simple as that

Comment: This way will duplicate the content of the string

Comment: Aaaand... this will not compile. In VB.NET the concatenator operator for strings is `&`, not `+`. I think you wanted to write this: `s &= "E"`

Comment: Pal SysDragon, the operator `&` and `+` is **almost similar in VB.Net not in C#**. So that it can concatenate the string but **`-` operator does not work with strings**.

Comment: Also GetAsyncKeyState will return a short, not a boolean.

Comment: Dominic Trade, me job to show that concatenate can be made using `+` operator not what ` GetAsyncKeyState ` function returns

Comment: Then it will compile and you can do it, but you [should not](http://www.lavanguardia.com/ciencia/20140416/54405869699/cientificos-barco-vela-titan-estudiar-mares.html) use `+` for concatenation, as it can be confused with addition operation. And, as @DominicTrade said, you're performing and implicit conversion with `GetAsyncKeyState` to `Boolean`

Comment: SysDragon, don't you think a centralized form is very much easier to remember?? If yes, then prefer `+` to addition of String and Integer both purpose. If no, all depends on you. But the way is not  wrong as the modern system is developed to simplifies the process of writing codes.

Comment: It is a debatible issue: [&vs+for-concatenating-strings-in-vbnet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006153/ampersand-vs-plus-for-concatenating-strings-in-vb-net). But it's safer and recommended to use `&` instead

Comment: I just said that this is a wrong conversion. Get Option Strict On!

Comment: Both **String+String can be concatenate** using that but **String+Integer is not supported**