# String is too long to fit on one line - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, string, visual-studio

I have a string that is 109000 characters in length, and it wont fit on one line, I get a "line is too long." error.
I know that with normal CODE you can do the "_" at the end of your code like

```
    this code is too long so I will use the _
    this code acts like it is on the same line
```

but in a string it takes the "_" to be part of a string (as it should). There is no information that I could find on this, so here it is for you guys, stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation on the "Line is too long" error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8tbya99%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) states that the maxiumum line length is 
65535, so this is why you are getting the error.

There are a few solutions:

You can concatenate the string using the `&`

```
Dim s As String = "this code is too long so I will use the" &
                  "this code acts like it is on the same line"
```

Note you can also use `+` to concatenate string but make sure you have Option Strict On if you do (`&` is safer as the result is always a String). See comparison between the two here: [Ampersand vs plus for concatenating strings in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006153/ampersand-vs-plus-for-concatenating-strings-in-vb-net)

You can use a string builder. This may be more efficient if you are continually adding strings to the original string (especially if you do this in a loop):

```
Dim sb As new StringBuilder
sb.Append("this code is too long so I will use the")
sb.Append("this code acts like it is on the same line")

Debug.Writeline(sb.ToString)
```

See MSDN for [More information about Concatenation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te2585xw.aspx)

Comment: For the top code shouldn't you use a "_" after the "&" to show you are moving to the next line? @Matt Wilko

Comment: @user3659330 - No. See the [VB coding conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h63fsef3(v=vs.120).aspx) that state "Avoid using the explicit line continuation character "_" in favor of implicit line continuation wherever the language allows it."

Answer (score -1):

```
Dim longString As String = "loooooooooooooooooooooooooo" + _
"ooooooooooooooggggggg"
```

Comment: why did I not think of that

Comment: @Fabio vbNewLine I mean here is during runtime, not on coding level.

Comment: Ok, but as I understand question was about writing string in code, thats why I ask.

Comment: Sorry if i din't specify it