# File setattribute not working

Tags: vb.net, setattribute

I am using the following command

```
IO.File.SetAttributes(Pth & FileP, FileAttributes.Hidden)
```

Its in a module which is called at the sub main but does not change the attributes of the file to hidden. Pth & FileP is a string "E:\Tareek.exe" which is a Usb storage device. The file attribute by default is not read only...

Can someone please tell me what the problem might be?

Comment: are you trying to set the file attrib *from* `Tareek.exe`?

Comment: trying to set the file Tareek.exe attribute to hidden.

Comment: yes, I understand that. are you trying to set `Tareek.exe` from `Tareek.exe`?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question.

Comment: Pth is "E:\" and FileP is "Tareek.exe

Answer (score 0):

Usually to set "hidden" you add that attribute instead of replacing as shown in MSDN article [File.SetAttributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setattributes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2):

```
 File.SetAttributes(path, File.GetAttributes(path) Or FileAttributes.Hidden)
```

Comment: im doing exactly that but it doesn't seem to like the command

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `option strict on` in your code because you will need to use the `+` instead of `&` for string concatenation in your parameter. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006153/ampersand-vs-plus-for-concatenating-strings-in-vb-net)