# Displaying all array contents in a textbox

Tags: arrays, vb.net, winforms

So I'm trying to add items into a array and then return all items in the array in a textbox. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? When I click the button, it errors out or I get `system.string[]` or it doesn't display all the items, just one full or partial item. edit1: here is the updated code.

```
   Public Class Form1
    Dim x As Integer = 0
    Dim strencode As String
    Dim strletters As String
    Dim strholder(0 To 999) As String


    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        strletters = TextBox1.Text
        Label2.Text = x.ToString
        If TextBox1.TextLength < x Then
            x = 0

        End If


        If TextBox1.TextLength <> 0 Then
            If TextBox1.TextLength < x Then
                x = 0
            End If



            Do Until x = TextBox1.TextLength
                If TextBox1.TextLength < x Then
                    x = 0
                End If
                If TextBox1.TextLength <> 0 Then
                    If strletters.Substring(x, 1) = "A" Then
                        strholder(x) = "346,"
                        x = x + 1
                    ElseIf strletters.Substring(x, 1) = "B" Then
                        strholder(x) = "917,"
                        x = x + 1
                    End If




                End If
            Loop


pause:





            Dim i As Integer
            For i = 0 To (x - 1)
                TextBox2.Text = (strholder(i))
            Next

        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: What error message on what line of code?

Comment: You should add what initial "state" / final "state" you expect/have to allow us to understand what you're trying to achieve (as functionality/behaviour) rather than what the code should do.

Comment: Update this line to: TextBox2.Text &= strholder(i)

Comment: or TextBox2.Text = String.Join("", strholder)

Answer (score 1):

Your `Do Until` block will continue indefinitely if you have any letter different from 'A' and 'B' in your `strletters` string. Be sure to always increment the x value:

```
Do Until x = TextBox1.TextLength
    ' Some conditions
    ' Some more conditions        
    x = x + 1 ' Increment regardless
Loop
```

Additionally, you can easily concatenate the output of your `strholder` array by using `String.Join`:

```
TextBox2.Text = String.Join(String.Empty, strholder)
```

Update:

Here's a code snippet with a couple of other methods...

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ' Converting a string to a char array
        Dim charArray() As Char = TextBox1.Text.ToCharArray
        ' Converting a string to a string array
        Dim stringArray() As String = TextBox1.Text.Select(Function(c) c.ToString).ToArray

        ' Concatenate using a For Each loop
        For Each ch In charArray ' or stringArray
            ' do something with each ch...
            TextBox2.Text &= ch ' Concatenate using the & operator
            'TextBox2.Text += ch ' Concatenate using the + operator
        Next

        ' Converting a char array back to a string
        TextBox2.Text = String.Join(String.Empty, charArray)
        ' Converting a string array back to a string, method 1
        TextBox2.Text = String.Join(String.Empty, stringArray)
        ' Converting a string array back to a string, method 2
        TextBox2.Text = stringArray.Aggregate(Function(final, sCh) final & sCh)

        ' In your case you could just simply...
        TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("A"c, "346,").Replace("B"c, "917,")
    End Sub
End Class
```

As for choosing a concatenation operator, you can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006153/ampersand-vs-plus-for-concatenating-strings-in-vb-net)