# Unable to download pdf file in. pdf extension in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am working on asp.net and i have to download pdf file from page. I wrote the following code, it download well but type of file become "file".

```
Response.Clear()
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=" + UnderProcessArticle_RadComboBox.SelectedValue) 
Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~\Articles\" + UnderProcessArticle_RadComboBox.SelectedValue + ".pdf"))
```

I want that when file download it would be in .pdf extention.what channging i should do????

Comment: You know if someone modified the value of that combo box, they could potentially request any file they want? Directory traversal attack.

Comment: Anyways, why don't you use the proper MIME type for a PDF? `application/pdf`

Comment: this is admin page ,only admin can access...but how i can solve this if want do such scenerio publically.

Comment: You forgot to add ".pdf" to the `filename=` part. And the string concatenation operator in VB is `&`, not `+`.

Comment: When a user selects a file to download, you should verify that they do indeed have access to that file. Rather than selecting them by filename, you might assign an ID to each file, then check what ID's the user should have access to. If they do have access, then retrieve the path to the file from your database. The important thing is that you can't trust user input.

Comment: yess..thankyou..it was the problem...+ is also working well in vb for concatenation

Comment: hi,
Also to add on how about you append the file name with Content-type. For example store content-type and append content-type with the end of the filename while you are saving. This way no matter which file type you save it will save the respective file accordingly example: .pdf , .jpg , png etc.,

Comment: i say just help that + is also working well in vb ..and what is the difference between + and & in vb..@AndrewMorton

Comment: @Ubaid [Ampersand vs plus for concatenating strings in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3006153/1115360).

Answer (score 0):

You must ensure the header Content Type returned is the correct one, so for `pdf` you cannot use `application/octet-stream`.

If you what to get the correct type from the file name use `System.Web.MimeMapping`

the bellow example is in C#, but I think you will understand..

```cs
response.Content.Headers.ContentType =
 new MediaTypeHeaderValue(MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fileName));
```